# How can I configure Symantec Endpoint Protection Agent to allow access to windows shares?

Tags: firewall, network-share, symantec

I'm having some difficulties exposing a standard windows file share on a Windows Embedded Standard 2009 device that is running Symantec Endpoint Protection Agent 5.1.

I'm using simply file sharing to expose a particular directory. That share is visible locally on the machine and externally visible when I disable the endpoint protection agent.

I've added a rule (and moved it to the to ensure priority) allowing all hosts access on TDP ports 137,138,138,445 and another rule allowing UDP access on ports 137,138,139. When I try to connect, two  endpoint protection dialogs pop up saying:

```
Traffic has been blocked from this application: NWLINK2 IPX Protocol Driver (nwlnkipx.sys)
Traffic has been blocked from this application: IPv6 driver (tcpip6.sys)
```

I'm not using IPv6 anywhere.

Interestingly, I discovered a workaround in that I can white-list all traffic from the subnet the device is on, which meets my needs, but I'm still curious as to why my original approach wasn't successful.

Can anyone suggestion a reason why the above endpoint protection rules won't allow me to access windows file shares on the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution : http://service1.symantec.com/support/ent-security.nsf/854fa02b4f5013678825731a007d06af/684e821eb0b394f8882575070060f2a4?OpenDocument

> To manually enable clients to browse for files and printers
>
> 1. In the client, in the sidebar, click Status.
> 2. Beside Network Threat Protection, click Options > Configure Firewall Rules.
> 3. In the Configure Firewall Rules dialog box, click Add.
> 4. On the General tab, type a name for the rule and click Allow this traffic.
> 5. On the Ports and Protocols tab, in the Protocol drop-down list, click TCP.
> 6. In the Remote ports drop-down list, type 88, 135, 139, 445.
> 7. Click OK.
> 8. In the Configure Firewall Rules dialog box, click Add.
> 9. On the General tab, type a name for the rule and click Allow this traffic.
> 10. On the Ports and Protocols tab, in the Protocol drop-down list, click UDP.
> 11. In the Remote ports drop-down list, type 88.
> 12. In the Local ports drop-down list, type 137, 138.
> 13. Click OK.
>
>     To manually enable other computers to browse files on the client
> 14. In the client, in the sidebar, click Status.
> 15. Beside Network Threat Protection, click Options > Configure Firewall Rules.
> 16. In the Configure Firewall Rules dialog box, click Add.
> 17. On the General tab, type a name for the rule and click Allow this traffic.
> 18. On the Ports and Protocols tab, in the Protocol drop-down list, click TCP.
> 19. In the Local ports drop-down list, type 88, 135, 139, 445.
> 20. Click OK.
> 21. In the Configure Firewall Rules dialog box, click Add.
> 22. On the General tab, type a name for the rule and click Allow this traffic.
> 23. On the Ports and Protocols tab, in the Protocol drop-down list, click UDP.
> 24. In the Local ports drop-down list, type 88, 137, 138.
> 25. Click OK.

Somehow I missed that during my initial searching. The version I'm using (5.1) didn't match the steps exactly, but once I implemented the rules, I was able to access my share.

I basically ended up creating 4 rules rather than the one that I was trying to do as well as adding the rules for port 88 (according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) this is Kerberos, which seems a little odd). Once this was done I was able to access my share as intended..